# MySQL trigger syntax error

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am just creating a trigger for MySQL. But I am getting the below error.

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'END' at line 1

Below is my code to create a trigger.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS user_contact_after_insert;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `user_contact_after_insert`
AFTER INSERT ON `forum_user`
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `user_contact` (email) VALUES (LCASE(NEW.FIRST_NAME NEW.LAST_NAME+'@gmail.com'));
  END;
DELIMETER ;
```

Here I have two tables `forum_user` & `user_contact`. In `forum_user` table I have four column like `ID`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `Date` and in `user_contact` table I have two columns `ID` & `email`.

Now Here I want to create trigger which will insert a row at user_contact table when one row  will insert into the forum_user table with the recent value from `first_name` & `last_name`.

Am I doing anything wrong in this code.
Any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the `DELIMITER` and use `CONCAT`

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS user_contact_after_insert;

DELIMITER // 

CREATE TRIGGER `user_contact_after_insert` 
AFTER INSERT ON `forum_user` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO `user_contact` (email) 
    VALUES (LCASE(CONCAT(NEW.FIRST_NAME, NEW.LAST_NAME,'@gmail.com'))); 
END//    --- <<=== HERE

DELIMITER ;
```